# select closest row that has one value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of days like this

```
CREATE TABLE `date` (
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `feriado` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- 
-- Volcar la base de datos para la tabla `date`
-- 
INSERT INTO `date` VALUES ('2016-10-28', 0);
INSERT INTO `date` VALUES ('2016-10-29', 0);
INSERT INTO `date` VALUES ('2016-10-30', 1);
INSERT INTO `date` VALUES ('2016-10-31', 1);
INSERT INTO `date` VALUES ('2016-11-01', 0);
INSERT INTO `date` VALUES ('2016-11-02', 0);
INSERT INTO `date` VALUES ('2016-11-03', 0);
```

and this query that add dates

```
SELECT ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2+(select COUNT(fecha) FROM date where fecha BETWEEN curdate() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND feriado=1) DAY)
```

How can I make that if the result date has feriado=1, it returns the closest one in the future that has feriado=0?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide the desired result. (It seems like feriado should be a TINYINT)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE date (
  fecha date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  feriado tinyint NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `date` VALUES 
('2016-10-28', 0),
('2016-10-29', 0),
('2016-10-30', 1),
('2016-10-31', 1),
('2016-11-01', 0),
('2016-11-02', 0),
('2016-11-03', 0);

SELECT x.* 
     , MIN(y.fecha) nearest
  FROM date x
  LEFT
  JOIN date y
    ON y.fecha >= x.fecha
   AND y.feriado = 1
 GROUP 
    BY x.fecha;

+------------+---------+------------+
| fecha      | feriado | nearest    |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 2016-10-28 |       0 | 2016-10-30 |
| 2016-10-29 |       0 | 2016-10-30 |
| 2016-10-30 |       1 | 2016-10-30 |
| 2016-10-31 |       1 | 2016-10-31 |
| 2016-11-01 |       0 | NULL       |
| 2016-11-02 |       0 | NULL       |
| 2016-11-03 |       0 | NULL       |
+------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: I have edited the answer & results, because he is not asking for next holiday but for next working day. Beside that it is very nice written answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the second next day with feriado = 0, then another approach could be to sort and pick:

```
SELECT max(fecha) FROM (
  SELECT fecha FROM date
  WHERE feriado = 0
  AND fecha > curdate()
  ORDER by fecha
  LIMIT 2
) AS foo;
```